# How to import DAG with specific Parameters

Tags: google-cloud-composer

I have a DAG that I want to launch in Composer with some parameters.
I can't use Airflow Global Variables as I want to launch the same DAG with different "Context". My Parameters representing this context

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create a dag as a function on a separate file and then just reuse you dag code with different dag configurations. Below represents is the approach in pseudo code:

**Dag Folder**

```
#ie:
#machine_export.py
#car_export.py
#plane_export.py

from logic import export_pub_template

config = {
'param1': ...
'param2': ...
}

with DAG(dag_id='',
         ...
     ) as dag:

   export_pub_template(config)
```

**Logic Folder**

```
#push_data_template_dag.py 

def export_pub_template(config):

  get_data = get_data_custom_operator(config.params)
  export_data = send_data_to_db(config.params)

  get_data >> export_data
```

Also, here is also a similar [approach](https://towardsdatascience.com/break-up-a-big-airflow-dag-into-multiple-files-5262accf6713). It follows the same pattern which is to break up the DAG code so you can reuse it in similar DAGs.

For details about writing DAGs you can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/writing-dags).